# how can I apply my jQuery function in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to create html5 video player in Reactjs component. But I don't know how can I implement the jQuery code in react component.

My test is based on this : [link jquery method to make video player](https://jsfiddle.net/9ewogtwL/181/)

Is this best practice to implement paused an play native function ?

```
 function PlayVideo() {
  $('.video').parent().click(function () {
    if ($(this).children(".video").get(0).paused) {
      $(this).children(".video").get(0).play();

    }
  });
}

    class playVideo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){

    var wrapper = {
      display:'table',
      width:'auto',
      position:'relative',
      width:'50%'
    };

    var video = {
      width: '100%',
      border: '1px solid white'
    };

    var play = {
      backgroundImage:'url(http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/2315/default_icon/256/media_play_pause_resume.png)',
      backgroundRepeat:'no-repeat',
      width:'50%',
      height:'50%',
      position:'absolute',
      left:'0%',
      right:'0%',
      top:'0%',
      bottom:'0%',
      margin:'auto',
      backgroundSize:'contain',
      backgroundPosition: 'center'
    };

    return(
      <div style={wrapper}>
      <video style={video}>
        <source src="http://e14aaeb709f7cde1ae68-a1d0a134a31b545b257b15f8a8ba5726.r70.cf3.rackcdn.com/projects/31432/1427815464209-bf74131a7528d0ea5ce8c0710f530bb5/1280x720.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <div class={play}></div>
      </div>
    )

  }
}

playVideo.displayName = 'playVideo';
export default playVideo;
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](http://tech.oyster.com/using-react-and-jquery-together/)

Comment: Too difficult for me I don't understand.